# Can I play a game inside windows in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

So I want to play Pubg lite, is there anyway to play it using ubuntu? 
And if I installed windows 10 in virtual box is it possible to play it smoothly?

Ubuntu version is 19.04

Comment: You can try to download the PUBG .exe file and then install it in your Ubuntu system using Wine. Hope it will help. I don’t know if you can play it in a virtual device. It will be related to your system specifications like RAM and graphics card.

Comment: Be aware that advice on 3D graphics in VirtualBox on the suggested duplicate may be out of date. I believe there has been significant work in recent years around 3D support in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want to play Pubg lite, is there anyway to play it using ubuntu?

Natively: No. It requires dotnet as we do not have that. The best next alternative is virtualization. If you have a Windows license you can also dual boot.

> And if I installed windows 10 in virtual box is it possible to play it smoothly?

Yes, Windows virtualised is almost the same as a normal Windows. The only thing you miss is a bit of power: you run an OS inside an OS. A nice amount of RAM is advisable.  Mind though that in theory you could set the amount of RAM used by Windows pretty high if you do not use Ubuntu at the same time.